# Wordpress how to call custom php from theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress.

I want to call the custom php pages from WordPress theme directly. I don't want to create a page template and link it to pages.

for eg:

```
www.mydomain.com/customer-account/personal-profile
www.mydomain.com/customer-account/weight-management-chart
www.mydomain.com/customer-account/my-orders
www.mydomain.com/customer-account/notifications
```

In my theme i will create 4 php pages and somehow i want to access without doing anything in the admin. It is possible to do?

Thanks to all

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407966/include-wordpress-theme-in-a-custom-php-page

Comment: You are looking for endpoints API. [Check this link](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/)

Comment: Thanks but i want to do without any plugin.

Comment: nilambar - i am checking your reference link, do you know how it works for woo-commerce plugin? you can see pages under template/my-accounts/ it can be accessed by the url. I want exactly like this

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [add actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to your functions.php to insert the code into each page. You would use [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) to insert the code into the appropriate spot in the appropriate page.

Comment: thanks and can you tell me how to add actions to create a page.

Comment: i checked the add actions and is page but i can't understand how to create pages